# I want to add the a feature where the program to ask the user if they want to continue

Tags: java, while-loop

I want to add a feature to my while loop if they want to try again but I don't know where to put the code. If the user enters <kbd>N</kbd>, the code shall stop and if he enters <kbd>Y</kbd>, it shall re-ask for the start, end and step.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sum3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int start, end, step;
        char option;
        
        
        System.out.print("Enter START value: ");
        start = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter END value: ");
        end = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter STEP value: ");
        step = input.nextInt();
         
        while (start > end)
            System.out.println("Start is larger than End");

        while (step == 0)
            System.out.println("Step is larger than the zero");

        while (true)
            for (int i = start; i < end; i += step)
                System.out.println(i);

        /*System.out.println("Would you still want to continue? (Y/ N)");
        option = input.next().charAt(0);*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Extract your code into a method and call this method in another loop where you can check the retry option

Comment: Note: all of your `while` will never stop if entered once. Since you're just printing some text I think `if` would be better

Comment: @StefanWarminski oh thats explains it, though i also want the program to ask if the user wants to try again when the program has successfully ran

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few significant problems in your code.
Like all of your while loops are infinite. You can just use "if-else" instead.
Next, I'm not sure why you put that for loop inside that endless while loop.
What you can do instead is, do your printing inside for loop and then ask if they want to retry. Here's an example :

```
for (int i = start; i < end; i = i + step)
{
     System.out.println(i);
     System.out.println("Retry (Y/N) : ");
     option = input.nextChar();
     if (option == 'N')
     {
          break;
     }
}
```

Comment: You should not ask for Retry in the loop, as this would mean asking after every number in the range is printed. The loop should only print the numbers, then the Retry (Y/N) should be asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a do-while loop and put all your logic within it. So basically it should begin before your first sysout and should end after your commented code at the end.

But there are some other problems in your code. For example,

1. while(step == 0) should be if(step == 0) or better if(step <=0), because you want to show the message if step is 0 or negative, otherwise you want to print the numbers, correct?
2. You don't need the while(true) around the for loop. For loop itself should be enough.

Take this as a suggestion and build around your code.